# I have following javascript code which is not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables

I am new to javascript and learning it. I use Brackets as an editor. I have the following code, but it is not showing any result:

```js
var v2 = 30;

function fun1() {
  var v1 = 20;
  document.write = ("The value of v1 in fun 1 =" + v1 + "<br/>");
  document.write = ("The value of v2 in fun 1 =" + v2 + "<br/>");
}

fun1();

document.write = ("The value of v2 outside fun 1 =" + v2 + "<br/>");
```

Comment: Typo: You put a `=` between the name of the function (write) and the arguments to it.

Comment: Consider not using document.write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `document.write` instead of assigning a value.

```
document.write(
//            ^
```